# Filtrar solo las fechas que correspondan a las ultimas 24 horas

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo un array con fechas en milisegundos, generadas con `Date.now()`.

```
array = [
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713426497 },
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713439057 },
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713459702 },
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713480404 },
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713495310 },
  { publicIP: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', date: 1671713500586 }
]
```

Ahora mismo es 22 de diciembre de 2022 y son las 9.55am, yo quiero eliminar del array todas las fechas anteriores al 21 de diciembre de 2022 a las 9.55am. Es decir, solo quiero conservar las ultimas 24 horas de registros.

Como puedo hacer esto? Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera, pero cuando lo pruebo con 1 segundo o 1 minuto, no se limpia el array. Tengo algun problema en esta logica?

```
const clear24hs = array => {
  const now = Date.now(); // Timestamp ahora mismo
  const aDay = 86400000;  // 24 horas en milisegundos
  const diff = now - aDay; // al now le resto 24 horas

  // finalmente devuelvo solo los elementos con la fecha mayor a diff
  return array.filter(el => el.date >= diff);
}
```

Comment: no puede haber doble return, tienes un return demás dentro del filter.

Comment: ese return puedo eliminarlo y dejar la funcion filter en 1 sola linea, pero la funcion filter siempre va a tener ese return implicito o explicito ahi, o me equivoco? Ahi edite la pregunta, porque lo saque de mi codigo y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Creo que estoy medio quemado y estoy haciendo algo matematicamente incorrecto.

Comment: Tu código me funciona, haz log a `diff` y agrega valores en tu objeto que sean menores a eso, veo que no se filtran.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev creo que tengo un problema con las fechas y el timestamp. Si yo tomo Date.now() obtengo un timestamp. Si a ese timestamp le resto 60000 espero obtener la misma hora, con un minuto de diferencia. Pero en consola del navegador estoy haciendo ``new Date(Date.now(timestamp))`` y la diferencia es de 27 segundos en lugar de ser de 1 minuto

Comment: Otra cosa que no entiendo, Diff es 27 segundos MAYOR que now, segun la consola de node... no entiendo como los estoy restando y me da una fecha mayor jaja

Comment: Creo que será por el tiempo de ejecución de línea por línea, el primer log agarra cierto segundo y el segundo log agarra otros segundos después, no todo se ejecuta al mismo tiempo (creo).

Comment: Creo que lo solucioné reemplazando ``const now = Date.now();`` por ``const now = new Date()``, pero no entiendo porque esto me anda y lo anterior no. Tampoco entiendo porque a vos te anduvo.

Answer (score 0):

Que haces pa?, mira la lógica que tenes para filtrar los elementos del array es correcta. Sin embargo, tenes un problema en la comparación de las fechas.

La función Date.now() te devuelve el número de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Por lo tanto, el valor que devuelve esta función aumenta a medida que transcurren los milisegundos.

En cambio, estás comparando los valores de date con el valor de diff, que es el resultado de restarle a now un día (86400000 milisegundos). Esto significa que estás comparando el valor de date con una fecha anterior a la actual.

Para corregir esto, en lugar de restarle un día a now, debes sumarle un día a diff. De esta manera, estas comparando los valores de date con una fecha posterior a la actual, que es lo que queres hacer para filtrar solo los elementos de las últimas 24 horas.

aca te paso como deberia ser amigacho.

```
const clear24hs = array => {
  const now = Date.now(); // Timestamp ahora mismo
  const aDay = 86400000;  // 24 horas en milisegundos
  const diff = now + aDay; // al now le sumo 24 horas

  // finalmente devuelvo solo los elementos con la fecha mayor a diff
  return array.filter(el => el.date >= diff);
}
```

Con este cambio, vas a poder filtrar correctamente los elementos del array para conservar solo las últimas 24 horas.

Un saludo internauta!

Comment: Hola crack, como andas? Pongamos un ejemplo practico. Tengo un registro del ``22 de diciembre a las 00.00`` (hace 12 horas atras, no quiero eliminarlo). Hago un ``timestamp`` ahora mismo, y me da ``22 de diciembre a las 12.00``. Si yo al timestamp le sumo 24 horas, y lo guardo en ``diff``, ahora diff deberia ser ``23 de diciembre 12.00``. O no? En este caso, el registro ``22 de diciembre a las 00.00hs`` (el.date) nunca va a ser mayor al registro ``23 de diciembre 12:00hs``(diff), por lo tanto me devuelve un array vacio, y tendria que devolver el unico registro que tenia. Disculpa y mil gracias

Comment: Yo lo solucioné asi: ``const now = new Date(); const startDate = new Date(now); startDate.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - 1440);``, con eso genero las dos fechas, ``now`` es ahora mismo y ``startDate`` corresponde a hace 24hs. Dentro del filter, primero genero una fecha con el timestamp de los registros ``const date = new Date(el.date);`` y finalmente retorno en base a la condicion ``return date >= startDate;``.

Comment: Sí, tu solución es correcta y es otra forma de hacer lo mismo que te propuse anteriormente.

En tu código, primero obtienes la fecha y hora actual con new Date() y luego generas una nueva fecha con new Date(now) que corresponde a las mismas horas, pero del día anterior. Esto lo logras restando 1440 minutos (24 horas) con setMinutes().

Luego, dentro del método filter(), obtienes la fecha del elemento del array con new Date(el.date) y comparas si esta fecha es mayor o igual a la fecha de inicio (startDate). Si se cumple esta condición, el elemento se incluye en el array resultante.

Comment: const clear24hs = array => {
  const now = Date.now(); // Timestamp ahora mismo
  const aDay = 86400000;  // 24 horas en milisegundos
  const startDate = now - aDay; // Fecha inicio: now menos 24 horas
  const diff = now + aDay; // Fecha final: now más 24 horas

  // finalmente devuelvo solo los elementos con la fecha mayor o igual a startDate y menor a diff
  return array.filter(el => el.date >= startDate && el.date < diff);
}

Comment: @AgustinG. estás hablando con chatGPT, prácticamente xd

Comment: nada que ver pa, trabajo en esto hace mas de 35 años...